# Python Scrapy-Selenium Pagination problem

Tags: python, selenium, pagination, scrapy

I can't nail how to follow pagination on that site (check in start_urls). What it does is open webdriver, successfully grabs data from 1st page and while loading second it closes webdriver and thats it.

```
import scrapy
from lxml.html import fromstring
from ..items import PontsItems
from selenium import webdriver


class Names(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'enseafr'

    download_delay = 5.0

    start_urls = ['https://www.ponts.org/fr/annuaire/recherche?result=1&annuaire_mode=standard&annuaire_as_no=&keyword=&PersonneNom=&PersonnePrenom=&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2023&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2022&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2021&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2020&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2019&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2018&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2017&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2016&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2015&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2014&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2013&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2012&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2011&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2010']

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    def parse(self, response):
        items = PontsItems()
        self.driver.get(response.url)

        next = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="next"]')
        #'//*[@id="zoneAnnuaire_layout"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div[11]/a[4]'
        while True:

            try:
                next.click()

                for item in response.xpath('//div[@class="single_desc"]'):
                    name = item.xpath('./div[@class="single_libel"]/a/text()').get().strip()
                    description = item.xpath('./div[@class="single_details"]/div/text()').get()
                    description = fromstring(description).text_content().strip()
                    year = item.xpath('./div[@class="single_details"]/div/b/text()').get()

                    items['name'] = name
                    items['description'] = description
                    items['year'] = year
                    yield items

            except:
                break

        self.driver.close()
```

I'm really stuck at this thing for few days now.

Comment: Hi what seems to be the problem?

Comment: I'm getting this: selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.102)

Comment: if you use `Chrome` to click items then you should search in `self.driver.page_source` instead of `response` or simply use `self.driver.find_element_by_xpath` instead of `response.xpath` to search values.

Comment: When I use self.driver.find_element_by_xpath I get: TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not iterable tho not to mention something completely new like [984:16892:0918/012923.411:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(208)] [01:29:23.411] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1074 Getting Default Adapter failed.
 O_o can You guys explain this magic to me or better yet rewrite this script to actually work to some degree?

Comment: First put the next inside the try catch.

Comment: This change still only gets me thru 1st page and starts loading to second page and closes script without writing second page data... Im clueless whats up with this shit

Comment: Also the loop doesn't really look like it's appending after the yield since it's in the loop but not after. Also the values seem to be set to the last ones.

Comment: Yield is a return btw so It'll exit.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to use PontItems() but I can use an empty list to show how I would I return data with the following. It returns the current list if there is an error and appends to a list every time you click next to a new page. You only got one element so use find_elements.

```
items=[]
while True:
    try:
        next = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="next"]')
        next.click()
        descs = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="single_desc"]')
        for item in descs :
            name = item.xpath('./div[@class="single_libel"]/a/text()').get().strip()
            description = item.xpath('./div[@class="single_details"]/div/text()').get()
            description = fromstring(description).text_content().strip()
            year = item.xpath('./div[@class="single_details"]/div/b/text()').get()
            items.append({'name':name,'description':description,'year':year})
    except:
        break
yield items
```

Comment: Did you test it for that site? For me the only thing it changes is fetching last item data and still closes before changing to 2nd page